# How to check if two sparse matrices are equal in python

Tags: python, scipy

I have `a` and `b` in in Compressed Sparse Column format, generated by `scipy.sparse.csc_matrix()`. I know that we can use

```
(a!=b).nnz==0
```

to check if the sparsities of two arrays are equal, but how about the nonzeros? I have tried:

```
np.allclose(a.A, b.A)
```

But it gives me an error like this:

```
*** MemoryError
```

Is there any function that I can use to check if `a` and `b` are equal?

Comment: Just asking... No way I can check it myself. Would this work? `(a!=b).data==0 `

Comment: If the representations are unique (I assume they are), then this should work: `a.data == b.data & a.indices == b.indices & a.indptr == b.indptr`.

Comment: @Marcel `(a!=b).data==0` seems work! Thank you very much.

Comment: @Marcel I have tried `a.data==b.data`. It generates an error when the two sparse matrices are not the same: `DeprecationWarning: elementwise comparison failed; this will raise an error in the future.`

Comment: glad it works! Maybe compare indices and index pointers just in case. Hope same syntax works.